# Jest: Mocking third-party modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have been trying to learn unit testing with Jest recently, reading through the docs and various articles.

One thing I have not been able to figure out is the following:

I am trying to test a nodeJS module that has an `if` statement conditional on `os.platform()`.

Is there any way for my test to set/mock the `os.platform` return value to something else, so when the Jest runs the test file the test file will read the os.platform() value specified in the test suite?

PS: `foo()` cannot accept the platform via dependency injection. The implementation of `foo()` is fixed.

**myModule.js**

```
import os from 'os';
export const foo = () => {
  if (os.platform() === `win32`) {
    module = module.split(`\\`).join(`\\\\`);
  }
}
```

**myModule.test.js**

```
import * as myModule from '../myModule.js';

// Guessing I need to use spyOn, to test the actual module code?
const myModuleMock = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'foo');

describe('myModule', () => {
  it('can run with different os.platform() values', () => {
    myModuleMock();
    expect(myModuleMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // How do I specify what value os.platform() in foo() should return?
  });
});
```

Comment: My advice is learn how to do it with Mocha and Sinon instead. There is a lot of documentation and examples already created.

Comment: I would import `os` and see if I can affect it by mocking (or stubbing) the method your function is using in the `if` statement

Comment: Try change your code so it uses aggregation or dependency injection. It will allow you for an easier way to unit test it. In this case, you could mock/stub `os` and then pass it to your code.

Comment: I've added an example using your own test code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import `os` into your test file and use `jest.spyOn` to mock it like this:

```
import * as myModule from '../myModule.js';
import os from 'os';

describe('myModule', () => {
  it('can run with different os.platform() values', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(os, 'platform');
    spy.mockReturnValue('mocked response');  // <= mock the return value

    myModule.foo();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```

I prefer this approach because it keeps the mock closer to the test that it is affecting.

---

If you want to use `jest.mock` with a factory function then you can do it like this:

```
jest.mock('os', () => { 
  const os = jest.requireActual('os');
  jest.spyOn(os, 'platform').mockReturnValue('mocked response');
  return os;
});
```

Note that the factory function must be completely self-contained.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's a useful technique.

Comment: Brian, thanks. It is not necessary to use `spyOn` there though, right? I got it to work by just doing:`jest.mock('os', () => { return { platform: jest.fn() } } );` Then, in my test I did: `os.platform.mockReturnValue('customPlatformValue'); myModuleMock(); `.

Comment: Yeah, that works fine too.  You can even simplify it to `jest.mock('os', () => ({ platform: jest.fn() }));`...just make sure no other code running during the test needs `os` since that replaces *everything* in `os`.  @Magnus

Answer (score 5):

You can mock the `os` module by adding a `os.js` file on the `__mocks__` dir:

```
// ./__mocks__/os.js
const os = jest.requireActual('os')

os.platform = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('testPlatform')
module.exports = os
```

```
// ./tests/whatever/some.test.js
import os from 'os'

jest.mock('os')

test('os', () => {
  expect(os.platform()).toBe('testPlatform') // ✔️
})
```

or, with just a single file:

```
const mockOS = jest.requireActual('os')
mockOS.platform = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('testPlatform')
jest.mock('os', () => mockOS)

import os from 'os'

test('os', () => {
  expect(os.platform()).toBe('testPlatform')
})
```

so your test file should look something like:

````
const mockOS = jest.requireActual('os')
mockOS.platform = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('testPlatform')
jest.mock('os', () => mockOS)


import * as myModule from '../myModule.js';

describe('myModule', () => {
  it('can run with different os.platform() values', () => {
    myModuleMock();
    expect(myModuleMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});```
````

Comment: Thank you. Trying to make your last example work. import must be at top no? Is it necessary with both require and import?

Comment: So, if I run foo() from within that test, then foo() in myModule.js will read the platform value I set in the test?

Comment: I moved import to the top, but get the following error: `ReferenceError: mockOS is not defined`, within `jest.mock`

Comment: the `jest.mock` call is hoisted to the TOP, however i suggest keeping it before the import.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Is myModuleMock defined anywhere? Oh, you are just missing the spyOn from my code. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: I tried the exact code you shared at the bottom, enapupe. Still getting: `ReferenceError: mockOS is not defined`. Any idea?

Comment: I discovered something interesting. The body of the jest test file does not run. In fact, only the second argument to your jest.mock runs (i.e. the factory).

Comment: Ah, the issue was as you said that in your code jest.mock is hoisted to the top. Thus, mockOS had not been defined when jest.mock ran. I swapped it out with jest.doMock, which avoids the hoisting. Now it seems to work. Running a few more tests before accepting.

Comment: ES6 `import` statements are hoisted so it's important to keep the hoisting behavior of `jest.mock`.  If you really want to use `jest.mock` then the factory function must be self-contained...I added an example to my answer to show how it can be done. @Magnus